# How to show a list of normal and group by items in one Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with some data in it and I need to showed into a list, but some data(or items) need to be hidden and then grouped as a unique element and not show each of them

This is to print a receipt, I need to show the list of items or materials used to fix the car or bicycle.

This is my code right now, my client told me yesterday about the grouped items and now I need to change it, but that I have a doubt about how can I do it...maybe make two SELECT?

```
//mantenimiento is the row that have the 1 or 0

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT nombre, vendido, ventaUnitaria, descuento, referenciaVenta, mantenimiento
FROM COMPRA WHERE id = :id");
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sql->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Per example, there are those items in the table (like right now is shhowed):

`chain fixed  ---  $100
clean ---   $12  *
carwash --- $35  *
filter --- $10  *
grease --- $7  *`

But in the list need to show only these:

`Chain fixed --- $100
Preventive Maintenance  --- $64`

In the table those items have a extra row with a number 1, the others items have 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to show some detail items but then sum up the other items and present them as a single item. You can present both types of results by performing a UNION of two separate SELECT queries. For example:

```
SELECT description, price from the_table
    WHERE id = ? and description = 'list-individual-charge-condition'
UNION
SELECT 'Preventive Maintenance' as description, sum(price) as price from the_table 
    WHERE  id = ? and description = 'aggregate-charge-condition'
;
```

Of course, you need to select the columns that are appropriate for your situatuion and specify the two WHERE clauses that will determine which charges are to be listed individually and which charges are to be summed up as Preventive Maintenance.

Comment: I also thought about using a union, my only hesitation is if you want to have the raw data elsewhere (perhaps there is/one day will be a button for 'show full breakdown') you've got to do the query again to get it again but if you just manipulate it PHP side you can reuse it - but to be fair it doesn't ask for that here (which is why I upvoted the answer)

Comment: @jameson2012 What you say is a consideration.